# AngularJS: the controller function is not a function got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a AngularJS beginer.Here is my HTML:

```html
 <div class="col-md-12 footer" ng-controller="User">
  {{user.username||"ad"}}

 </div>
```

Here is my controllers.js:

```html
angular.controller('User', user);
function User($scope){
    $scope.user={
        'username':"wang",
        'password':"wanghao"
    }
}
```

And I linked the controller in the (I am sure the link is right):

```html
<script src="js/Angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="js/Angular/controllers.js"></script>
```

But，when I run my code,here is the result:

```html
{{user.username||"ad"}}
```

Here is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX8xM.png)
I am really confused.I tried to write the JS in the HTML,or link the Javascript before the controller.But it still didn't work!!

Comment: controller function name is User, not user. try it first. 

angular.controller('User', user);
function User($scope){
    $scope.user={
        'username':"wang",
        'password':"wanghao"
    }
}

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/airwind711/e2onyhf5/

Answer (score 1):

It's this part, capitalization on your function.

```
angular.controller('User', user);
function user($scope){
    $scope.user={
        'username':"wang",
        'password':"wanghao"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function names are wrong in the controller and the function.

Just change it to `function user($scope)`

OR

You can declare your controller function directly like this:

```
angular.controller('User', function($scope){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col-md-12 footer" ng-app="app" ng-controller="User">                
    {{user.username||"ad"}}
 </div>

 //---Controller---//
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('User', function($scope){
 $scope.user={
    'username':"wang",
    'password':"wanghao"
 }
 });
```